# Broadcast Receiver, Notification Android

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have an application using broadcast receiver.

I want to send a notification to the user but sometimes it works, sometimes not.
The following code above its my implementation.

**MANIFEST.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />      
<application>
    <receiver android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions.NotificationService"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </service>
</application>
```

**SERVICE**

```
package com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions;

import com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.MainActivity;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

public static final int time = 60 * 1000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE CREATE");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE START");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "Passou SERVICE COMMAND");
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true){
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                    showNotification();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void showNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
            .setContentText("Test Notification.")
            .setSmallIcon(
                    com.polifrete.polifreteandroid.R.drawable.ic_actionbar)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*10000), n.build());

}

}
```

**BROADCAST**

```
package com.polifrete.polifreteFunctions;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Script", "Passou RECEIVER");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it passing on receiver, sometime not passing... What i need to do to always pass on receiver?

Comment: services don't have `launchMode`s, so remove that from the manifest.

Comment: You need to start an Activity after you install the application on the device, otherwise your `BroadcastReceiver` will not get triggered.

Comment: On ADV its working, but on phone not working... any ideia?

Comment: I'm getting this in my log when i run on phone: 06-15 13:05:29.671: V/RenderScript(7593): 0x5fd6f5d8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not passing". Also, the log line you wrote in the comment is useless and has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time after installing the application it will be in disabled state unless it is manually opened by user. So until the application is in disabled state all of the component like service, broadcast receiver and activities will also be in disabled state. Hence your application will not be opened from any external events other then manual intervention. So you need to open the application at least once manually to receive these boot completed intents.

Comment: I've closed and opened the application many times, and nothing happen... does you have any ideia why it happen with me?

Comment: How are you opening your application? Have you declared any activities?

Comment: Yes, i have a splashscreen, and than start another activity the "main" activity

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs? Which device are you using? This receiver gets executed only during start up of the device. Is this case what you are testing?please post the correct logs.

Comment: i've turned off my device and on again, and begin to send the notifications...  have any way to send it without turn off the device, only opening the app?

Comment: the receiver not getting executed when i was debugging... I need to turn off the device and on again, than begin to send the notifications. I'm using a galaxy S3 to test it. Can i start the receiver without turn off the device?

Comment: I did not understand your concern or issue here? Please take your time and explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: Sorry notable to join the chat. This only execute during phone bootup. If you want to send notification when you launch your application you have to start the service from activity

Comment: Than, if the user want to receive the notification, he will need to turn off the device and turn on again (for once time) to see the notification?

Comment: Not exactly. If the user wants to receive the notifications anytime. Then keep your application running all the time and push notifications to the user periodically